# How do I solve this for loop in C++?

Tags: c++

```
for(float i=1; i<=1.5; i+=0.1) 
{
  // statements
}
```

The above C++ for loop runs for 5 times. Shouldn't this run for 6 times?

Comment: You need to read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: If you represent 1.3 as `0.33333333`, how many times do you have to subtract 1/3 from 1 before it's less than or equal to zero?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great example of a floating point precision error. Precise values like multiples of 0.1, 0.2 cannot be precisely represented internally in the computer's memory. You'll want to do a comparison using EPSILON (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon)

Something like

```
for (float i = 1; fabs(1.5 - i) < EPSILON; i+=0.1) {
  //statements
}
```

Comment: better yet, convert to fraction and increment numerator

Answer (score 0):

It is because multiples of `0.1` cannot be presented precisely in binary, and the actual value stored is an approximation that may be slightly less than 0.1.   So, `5*0.1` might be less than 0.5 or it might be more (depending on how the floating point values are represented).

It is usually a really bad idea to use a floating point variable (and tests involving equality or inequality of floating point values) to control loops at all.   Effects can include running more (or less) times that intended, or - in some bad cases - an infinite loop where a finite number of runs was expected.

In your case, you would be better off doing something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
     float value = 1.0 * i*0.1;
       // use value here rather than the i in your original code
}
```

Alternatively, you can use some test that allows for the imprecision of floating point (e.g. compare `i - 1.5` with some value such as machine epsilon).   The catch with this is that the actual number of iterations still potentially has some level of unpredictability, particularly in loops that involve a large number of iterations (e.g. iterating from `1.0` to `50000.0` in steps of `0.01`) because rounding errors can either accumulate or cancel out at different stages during the loop.